# Which files get to the Recent files in MacOS?

Tags: macos, finder

I found that most of the files I create in different software on my Mac do not get to the Recent folder (I really love that simple feature when in Windows)

For example - I am generating 3d .STL file from CAD software, and saving it to Downloads folder. Going to the Recent Files folder (or using my hand-written Custom Search Folder "Date Modified = last 5 days") - I do not see the file there. 
After I open this file with any software, let us say I just opened this STL with Viewer software, - only after that the file gets to the Recent Files. That happens with 90% of files I am working on.

Can anyone get me a clue on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a file to get into the Recent files list, the creating application
must set the Extended Attribute of
[kMDItemLastUsedDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/kmditemlastuseddate).

Many apps do not set that metadata when you create the file or open it from
within the App, so it does not get into the list.

However, if you open a file from the Finder, this should set the attribute
and thus make it show up in the Recent files list.
Downloading a file, for example, does not make it part of the list.

For more information see the article
[MacOS Timestamps from Extended Attributes and Spotlight](https://forensic4cast.com/2016/10/macos-timestamps-from-extended-attributes-and-spotlight/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! However, that sounds very disappointing for me... Do you think I can emulate the behaviour of Windows Recent Files somehow? What is strange - is that theoretically my Custom Search Folders should work.. I only want  files Modified/Created in last 5 days. And these options are actually set on files. Should work, but not working...